# setcookie() doesn't work properly?

Tags: php, setcookie

Hi I'm trying to use cookies on my site. I created two test pages to try them out before I implement them in my site, but it doesn't seem to work well.

page one has:

```
<?php
setcookie("apple", "abc", time()+1500, "/", "b****a.org");
?>
```

page two has:

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["apple"];
?>
```

So to test it, I go to page one first, then I go to page two. For some reason, page two just outputs the letter "b" on the screen. That's it. I tried it on another computer, and it outputs "abcb" what's this b for? I'm guessing the cookie isn't getting stored on my computer, but it does work on two other computers so I guess it's just my problem. Anyways, why does it output an extra "b" at the end?

Thanks.

Comment: is your browser set to accept cookies? And try also to see the return of the setcookie function to see it succeeds (true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the cookie like this worked fine for me.

```
setcookie("apple", "abc", time()+1500);
```

Comment: Agree, that cookie example works good, possible problem can be the wrong last parameter domain name, or cookies are disabled in browser.

Comment: @user65940 Yes it works correctly, test2.php displays 'abc'. You have disabled cookies in browser. In Firefox they can be enabled [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences).

Comment: This is so weird. 10 minutes ago I tested this on TWO different computers and test2.php both outputed "abcb", even though I had "abc" as cookie value. Anyways, it works now. Btw, I do have cookies enabled. But I don't mind it not working on mine, as long as it works on others. :) Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Yet you can try to delete that cookie manually from browser cache and try to revisit again test1 and test2.php. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's some problem with your path or domain name, I used this on my local and it works perfect..

```
<?php
setcookie("mycookie", "This cookie tastes good", time()+3600, "", "localhost");

echo $_COOKIE['mycookie'];   //output : This cookie tastes good

//refresh twice if you are setting a cookie and using echo on a same page
?>
```

For more info on cookie : [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)